# How netvibes.com fetch emails from gmail when i disable pop and imap?

Tags: gmail, imap, pop3

I am trying to build a same gmail facility like in netvibes.com. But I am wondering how they read emails from gmail even when I disable pop and imap in my gmail account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using the Google inbox feed. http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/docs/inbox_feed.html